# Using different address template for billing and shipping

Tags: invoice, billing-address

One of my customer need to have **on the invoice** two different address template.

We need to "remove" from billing the "lastname name" like the following example

Billing to:

company name

address

postcode, ....

Shipping to:

lastname name

company name

address

postcode, ....

In the magento admin section I found only one template for address that is used for both shipping and billing.

Is there a way to differentiate it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the below paths,

```
app\design\frontend\yourtheme\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
app\design\frontend\yourtheme\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml
```

you can add or remove fields.

Comment: thanks you, but I need to have different fields displayed on the invoice (pdf) not on that page.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/

Comment: http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/

Comment: Try the above two links.